# send html form via post to webservice

Tags: forms, html, post

I'm very very new on HTML5 development and this question could be very silly but I've found an answer for it (or I've searched very well).

I want to send a form to a web service via post (I don't want to show all fields in URL).

I have two question:

1. **How must I named forms fields? If I trying to send an `userName` I think I have to put this test as ID to the field which will held that value.**
2. And this is because I'm so curious. Which is the post message content which is sent to web service?

This is an example that I've found searching Internet:

```
 <FORM action="http://somesite.com/prog/adduser" method="post">
    <P>
    <LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>
    <LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>
    <LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>
    <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
    <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </P>
 </FORM
```

I think I will need those ids to get those values while processing them on web service, isn't it?

Comment: Well, It all depends on the webservice.

If it's a [REST API][1] you can just POST to it.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you: How must I named forms fields?

Comment: That depends on the webservice, and the specification of the webservice. What webservice are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf What do you mean with: "What webservice are you trying to connect to?"? I haven't implemented the web service and I have to ask to someone. Are you asking about if it is a REST, SOAP or whatever web serive?

Comment: I didnt understand that you were going to implement your own webservice aswell, I thought you wanted to communicate with an already existing webservice.

Comment: @DavidEverlöf Yes, webservice exists.

Comment: You just said ' I haven't implemented the web service' and now you're saying 'Yes, webservice exists', I dont get it.

Comment: Ok, forget it. I will delete this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, you could do a post to a page with a redirect (in .NET you would handle it this way):

```
<form action="http://myurl/postpage.ashx" method="post">
    <input name="forename" />
    <input name="surname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then pick this up in the server side script at **postpage.ashx** using:

```
string forename = Request["forename"];
string surname = Request["surname"];
```

You could also use jQuery to make an ajax call to the same page using the following:

```
var forename = $("input[name=\"forename\"]").val();
var surname = $("input[name=\"surname\"]").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://myurl/postpage.ashx",
    type: "POST",
    async: true, // set to false if you don't mind the page pausing while waiting for response
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{ 'forename': '" + forename + "', 'surname': '" + surname + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        // handle your successful response here
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // handle your fail response here
    }
});
```

You would handle the post in the server side code the same way.  The key thing to note here is that whatever you enter as the **name** attribute of your input element is what will get POSTed as a key/value pair to your receiving URL.

Comment: can you give an exmaple how to retrieve the key/value pair in a (ASP.NET) webmethod? i have it like: 
[WebMethod(Description = "tests the method.")]
        public void TestMethod(String APP_VERSION_CODE)
        {
            // APP_VERSION_CODE should be the value or sth? i dont know..
        }

but I keep getting a ReportSenderException

Answer (score 0):

every web service should give you something like [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) which normally contains specification of available fields and methods you can use. if the webservice you are connecting to have url `webservice.com` than try `webservice.com/wsdl` to get the [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl).

Check this topic: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753098/how-get-html-post-data-and-pass-to-a-webservice)

Comment: I'm asking how I must send that fields. I think I have to set something on form to identify them. By the way, web service it isn't implemented yet.

Comment: look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753098/how-get-html-post-data-and-pass-to-a-webservice

Answer (score 0):

Attribute "name" is the one that needs to be unique in order to pass that parameter to a Servlet (or wherever). The post method then encrypts the message and sends it to the Servlet.

```
<form method="post" action = "LoginServlet">
     Name: <input type="text" name="userName">
     Password: <input type="password" name="password"> 

    <input type="submit" name = "Login" class="button">
</form>
```

In order to access that data you will do something like this in the Servlet:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
```